# Python: How to check if a word appears more than once in a text. (No Sets)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, file-io

In my assignment, I have a text and I want to count how many times that words appeared in the text. For example, let's say I have a text file saying.

I have lots of cats and dogs. I have 3 cats and 16 dogs. I love dogs!

Since the words dogs appeared 3 times, I need the output to be that number. However, how would I do this for a random text?

So far I've come up with the following.

```
file = open('phrases.txt')
text = file.read()
file.close()

count  = countWords()
duplicates = 0 

for words in text:
    if words #appear twice or more 

    #if duplicates 
    duplicates+=1 

unique = count - duplicates 
#subtract the total, by the amount of duplicates.
print(unique)
```

countWords() is another function I made which counts the amount of total words inside the text**

Comment: dictionaries`? collections.Counter?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  5N particular, we expect you to research your question before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

```
words = text.split()
counts = {}
for word in words:
if word not in counts:
    counts[word] = 0
counts[word] += 1

for k,v in counts.items() :
    if v==1 :
        print(k)
```

Comment: I'm getting KeyError at count[words]+=1

Comment: I tried my code it works perfectly,  the idea is you read lines from a file,  and store it in array using split() to remove whitespace from a line ,then you make a dictionary and store the world in a key and the count in a value, so you have every world with its count ,and that it, in the last for loop you are printing the unique words which have count =1, please vote up and choose the question as best answer and if you have any problem please contact me

Answer (score 1):

```
    text = "I have lots of cats and dogs. I have 3 cats and 16 dogs. I love dogs!"

    find = "dogs"
    count = 0

    for index, letter in enumerate(text):
        if letter == find[0]:
            word = text[index: index + len(find)]

            if word == find:
                count += 1

    print(count)
```